# calling a host function within a global function CUDA

Tags: cuda

Hello I am developing a program in CUDA C, where I have a class with some functions in the kernel I instantiate some functions of this class , more time to run it apppears the error

> calling the __host__ function ( " Perceptron :: inputAt " ) from the __global__ function ( "training" ) is not allowed

Anyone knows how occur ??

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. What is "asparece"? Please add more detail, and add some code and/or the exact error, then hopefully someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @drjimmie1976: The Portuguese verb for "to appear"

Answer (score 1):

Any class member functions which you call within CUDA device code must be declared as `__device__` functions. If you also need to call the member functions in host code, you need to declare the function as `__host__ __device__`.